# Create Singleton with function/constructor arguments (usefull for e.g. injection)

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, singleton

We use spring to construct/inject our java beans. Here a snippet:

```
<bean id="myAppConfigs" class="my.cool.webapp.ApplicationConfig" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="8080" />
    <constructor-arg value="MyAppName1" /> 
</bean>
```

We use the singleton-pattern in

```
public static ApplicationConfig getCurrentInstance(ServletContext sctx) {
    if (instance == null) {
                WebApplicationContext wac = null;
                if (sctx != null) {
                    wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sctx);
                }
return (ApplicationConfig) wac.getBean("myAppConfigs");
```

Since the bean is only reading some properties which are always the same I doubt there could be problems. But I'm still curious for a nice thread safe way to implement it
There is of course the [Double Checked Locking with usage of volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) which is  threadsafe. 
But is there another way maybe to use the [Initialization on demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom)  together with function/constructor arguments?

Comment: How exactly is this related to JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static ApplicationConfig getCurrentInstance(ServletContext sctx) {
  if (sctx == null) {
    throw new AssertionError("ServletContext is null");
  }
  WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sctx);
  if (wac == null) {
    throw new AssertionError("No ApplicationContext associated with ServletContext");
  }
  return (ApplicationConfig) wac.getBean("myAppConfigs");
}
```

This is plenty thread-safe. Better yet is to strive to use injection all the way (either through annotations or XML bean definitions), but that is not always possible.

Using Spring (DI) mixed with a singleton-pattern and explicit thread-synchronization is kind of anti-patternish and not really necesarry. The Spring bean factory is in itself thread-safe so you shouldn't need to add any additional locking/sync on top of it.